# Software to randomly mix and randomly rename files on a scammer's computer

Tags: file

I am an incipient scambaiter learning how to get control of a scammer's computer during their connection to mine (a virtual machine of course).  There are well known scambaiters that then copy the scammer's files to their computer and delete large blocs of files off of the scammer's computer.  I think, however, that the scammers can fairly easily recover from this situation if they maintain a comprehensive backup system.

I am thinking of a different procedure the might make it harder for them to get back in the game.  After copying files that might be useful, I am looking for software that would randomly move files individually and interspirse files to other directories.  Additionally, I would like to alter the names of the moved files.  I think this process would make it more difficult to restore their system.  This could make it a challenge to backup/restore back to original.  Plus the size of the altered disk and directories would be the same as before making it not so immediately obvious they had been attacked.

This does look like a programmable project for myself but I thought I would see what is out there for adaptation.

If this is seen as some kind of violation of the ethics of topics range of this BB, I will delete it

thanks,  tom kosvic

Comment: I don't see how restoring deleted files is different from restoring renamed or otherwise corrupt files. A backup is a backup and it has all your data that's worth keeping.

Comment: Into some startup file or commonly used command, insert something that once an hour (or some other period) picks a random file, changes a byte in it, and restores the change date.  It might take a while to do noticeable damage, but by then the added code will likely be part of the backups that will be used to correct the problem.